# image padding/align in objectlistview

Tags: alignment, padding, objectlistview

I'm using ObjectListView and TreeListView control, and I'm drawing an icon on a column/node, this way:

'defining the objectlistview/treelistview

```
OLV.SmallImageList = imgList
```

.
.
.

```
aNewColumn.ImageGetter = AddressOf GetImage
```

.
.
.

```
Friend Delegate Function GetImageDelegado(x As Object) As String

Friend Function GetImage(x As Object) As String

    Dim s As String

    s = x.ToString
    If imgList.Images.ContainsKey(s) = False Then
        Imagen = My.Resources.MyImage
        imgList.Images.Add(s, Imagen)
    End If

End Function
```

The issue I can't solve is that the icon is not vertically-centered:

[image: look at the blue ball]

I've been looking for paddings, adding decorations, but I can't manage to fix this...

I appreciate your help very much. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the images in your image list are properly formatted and have the correct size? If the icons are always alight left-top, you could just change your images to compensate.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! Yes, the images are correct! I don't want to change the images, because I use them for other things... i could have 2 sets of images, the "compensated" ones and the original ones, but it's too much work for a visual gap... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Trying to fix the issue, I've downloaded objectlistview source code and look for the image drawing... and I've found the drawing function correctly implements the vertical alignment...

So, I've compiled the source library and use that DLL and now it works! It's seems I had a previous version, spite of both DLL has the same version number (2.5.1.0)

Regards!

Comment: According to the site, yes, but 1) if I download "last stable version" I get 2.5.1; If I download 2.6 source code (.rar named "2.6") and compile the DLL, I get this: http://i41.tinypic.com/2076agx.png (and it is the right file, because I get no image gap)

Comment: Yes you are right. I checked the repository trunk and he fixed the version number with revision 691 (Update version number ----
Modified : /cs/trunk/ObjectListView/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs). This is still the latest code change to date. I did not check what revision the source from the download link represents.